# Google Maps API markers not placing

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to place some markers on the map [here](http://theadeizaproject.com/oversight) but no luck. Well actually it does show one marker which was called from the header as so:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC5Hacj2nz6Uby-AeesTPo8JVH5uGOnwlc">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
var map;
var markers;

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
    center:myCenter,
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position:myCenter

});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

that works, but when I try to add more markers, they don't come up. I'm using php with it so the code I'm running looks like this:

```
<?php

        global $wpdb;
            $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM REPORTS");

        foreach($results as $row){ ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                markers=new google.maps.Marker({
                    map:map,
                    position:new google.maps.LatLng(52,41)
                });
            </script>
        <?php
        } ?>
```

I should also mention that I'm using wordpress. This code checks out with no errors, and the echoes return a value so I don't know what it is, I started learning js/mysql last night. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change your approach a bit. Try reading out the data inside your JavaScript instead of creating a new script element for each marker. Then loop over this data with JavaScript to create the markers.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried switching it a bit but still no luck. Also, I tested it without the php loop in general, just a snippet that said add a new marker. I'm thinking the issue is with the map updating it's gui...?